# Ns3 installation stucks

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install ns3.34 on ubuntu 20.04 , and it stucks during installation.I increased the ram but it didnt work.

When i enter this command " ./build.py --enable-examples --enable-tests" it stucks in this line: " [2551/3008] compiling src/netanim/examples/star-animation.cc " and my system stops working.

After some time i got this error: g++ fatal error: killed signal terminated program cc1plus compilation terminated.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Edit your question and include enough details so that we can attempt to reproduce the problem on our end.

Comment: ns-3.35 : https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/getting-started.html ..... When building ns-allinone-3.34, the old "3.33" method should be preferred https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/installation-error-in-ns3-33-on-ubuntu-20-04-a-4175695350/#4  ..... `$ ./waf configure --enable-examples --enable-tests && ./waf build` : I got [3023/3023] → update → https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=6300987#post6300987

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 : Build example, ns-allinone-3.34

Prerequisites https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian.2FMint

```
$ sudo apt install python3-dev qt5-default libsqlite3-dev libdpdk-dev \
libgsl-dev libssh-gcrypt-dev libgtk-3-dev libboost-all-dev libxml2-dev \
python3-pygraphviz python3-pip sqlite3 gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0 python3-gi \
python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0 ipython3
$ sudo pip3 install pygccxml==2.1.0

$ wget https://www.nsnam.org/release/ns-allinone-3.34.tar.bz2
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-3.34.tar.bz2
$ cd ns-allinone-3.34/
$ ./build.py     
$ cd ns-3.34/
$ ./waf configure --enable-examples --enable-tests
$ ./waf build
.
[3023/3023] Creating pcfile: src/visualizer/libns3.34-visualizer-debug.pc
```